# How to retrospectively attach a / one fully defined but autonomous GUI element to another (DOM-attached) element

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, appendchild

I've been trying, step by step, to convert some very nice but static & non-d3 chordname-to-waveform [code](https://github.com/saebekassebil/teoria/tree/master/examples) for dynamic animation in a d3.js visualisation.

I've now reached a point where I have (in particular) two fully defined GUI elements, the first of which (plot) is already attached to the DOM:

```
var plot = plotframe
.append("svg")
.attr("whatever", ....
```

.. and the second (path, defined but as yet **DOM-unattached**) created using the following [curious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455282/how-to-create-svg-object-without-appending-it) syntax:

```
var path = d3.select(document.createElementNS(d3.ns.prefix.svg, "svg:path"))
.attr("id", "path")
.attr("whatever", ....
```

Prior to my changes (these elements becoming the subject of d3 selections), the raw elements were hooked up using:

```
plot.appendChild(path);
```

However, as path is subject to some cute wave-building algorithms which it would be a shame to disturb, how could I do a purely **retrospective** attach of (the now both d3 selections) path to plot? Something similar to appendChild, but d3-friendly.. Does d3.js cater for this at all?

I'm aware this resembles an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869414/appending-an-element-to-an-existing-element-in-d3-js), but the answer provided there is clearly not what I'm looking for.

Thanks
Thug

Comment: D3 doesn't provide any functionality for this. It's meant to operate on DOM elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both your selections each contain a single element, just extract the child element using `selection.node()` and then append it to the parent element.

You can either do that by extracting the node from the parent selection, and using `element.appendChild( node )`, or you can use `selection.append( functionThatReturnsANode )`.  Like this:

```
var plot = plotframe
.append("svg")
.attr("whatever", ....

var path = d3.select(document.createElementNS(d3.ns.prefix.svg, "svg:path"))
.attr("id", "path")
.attr("whatever", ....

plot.append( function(){return path.node();} );
```

You must use a function to return the node, you can't pass the node directly as a parameter.  This method was designed to work with selections containing many elements, and so you need a way of passing each one a different node to append.

Comment: Spot on. First automated chord (or compound) wave showing, together with it's component note waves.